# My powershell failed at the command prompt

Tags: displaytag

[The arrows were changed to rectangles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efcdC.png)
My powershell failed at the command prompt, I tried to fix it but still couldn't, I desperately need everyone's help, please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this font [MesloLGS NF Regular](https://github.com/romkatv/dotfiles-public/blob/master/.local/share/fonts/NerdFonts/MesloLGS%20NF%20Regular.ttf)

Comment: It's magical. I fixed it. I thank you very much, wishing you a happy and full of luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the powerline style plugin, but you are not picking the correct font for it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).